# Software for speech transcription

Tags: software-recommendation, speech-recognition

I have a bunch of audio files contained ordinary speech, mainly in mp3 format which I'd like to convert to text.  Does anyone know of software that can do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Speech-recognition app to convert MP3 to text?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161515/speech-recognition-app-to-convert-mp3-to-text)

Answer (score 4):

- [PocketSphinx homepage](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/)
- [pocketsphinx package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/pocketsphinx-lm-wsj)
- Old thread but interesting: [Pocketsphinx - Adding words and Improving accuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535208/pocketsphinx-adding-words-and-improving-accuracy)

Answer (score 0):

Try [Mozilla DeepSpeech](https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech) opensource application that can be run as a standalone application, or
[Transcribear](https://transcribear.com) browser based speech-to-text application, which will require to be connected online and upload the recording to the Transcribear server