# Speech-recognition app to convert MP3 to text

Tags: software-recommendation, speech-recognition

Does anyone know of an application that can convert audio to text?

Comment: I assume it is spoken text. Which language is that text in?

Comment: The speech text is in simple english.

Answer (score 34):

The software you can use is [Vosk-api](https://github.com/alphacep/vosk-api/), a modern speech recognition toolkit based on neural networks. It supports 7+ languages and works on variety of platforms including RPi and mobile.

First you convert the file to the required format and then you recognize it:

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp3 -ar 16000 -ac 1 file.wav
```

Then install vosk-api with pip:

```
pip3 install vosk
```

Then use these steps:

```
git clone https://github.com/alphacep/vosk-api
cd vosk-api/python/example
wget https://alphacephei.com/kaldi/models/vosk-model-small-en-us-0.3.zip
unzip vosk-model-small-en-us-0.3.zip
mv vosk-model-small-en-us-0.3 model
python3 ./test_simple.py test.wav > result.json
```

The result will be stored in json format.

The same directory also contains an srt subtitle output example, which is easier to evaluate and can be directly useful to some users:

```
python3 -m pip install srt
python3 ./test_srt.py test.wav
```

The example given in the repository says in perfect American English accent and perfect sound quality three sentences which I transcribe as:

```
one zero zero zero one
nine oh two one oh
zero one eight zero three
```

The "nine oh two one oh" is said very fast, but still clear. The "z" of the before last "zero" sounds a bit like an "s".

The SRT generated above reads:

```
1
00:00:00,870 --> 00:00:02,610
what zero zero zero one

2
00:00:03,930 --> 00:00:04,950
no no to uno

3
00:00:06,240 --> 00:00:08,010
cyril one eight zero three
```

so we can see that several mistakes were made, presumably in part because we have the understanding that all words are numbers to help us.

Next I also tried with the `vosk-model-en-us-aspire-0.2` which was a 1.4GB download compared to 36MB of `vosk-model-small-en-us-0.3` and is listed at https://alphacephei.com/vosk/models:

```
mv model model.vosk-model-small-en-us-0.3
wget https://alphacephei.com/vosk/models/vosk-model-en-us-aspire-0.2.zip
unzip vosk-model-en-us-aspire-0.2.zip
mv vosk-model-en-us-aspire-0.2 model
```

and the result was:

```
1
00:00:00,840 --> 00:00:02,610
one zero zero zero one

2
00:00:04,026 --> 00:00:04,980
i know what you window

3
00:00:06,270 --> 00:00:07,980
serial one eight zero three
```

which got one more word correct.

Tested on vosk-api 7af3e9a334fbb9557f2a41b97ba77b9745e120b3.

Comment: also, as an addition to this answer, there's a cool demo of both `speech recognition` and `voice command` tools here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gr1FZ2F7KYA&list=PLvB_ffZs45ufhOnw1epfjncXYRa5pfGw8&index=1

Comment: How do you add an acoustic model to the system?

Comment: You just download it and unpack, there is no such thing as "add to the system"

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev Where should I unpack it so that pocketsphinx_continuous finds it?

Comment: You can unpack it anywhere, pocketsphinx does not look in any location automatically, you have to specify model path in -hmm argument as pointed in the answer above.

Comment: Well, I installed packages pocketsphinx-utils, pocketsphinx-hmm-en-hub4wsj and pocketsphinx-lm-en-hub4 in universe repository of Ubuntu 14.04. Then `pocketsphinx_continuous -infile file.wav -hmm en_US/hub4wsj_sc_8k -lm en_US/hub4.5000.DMP 2> pocketsphinx.log` worked. Maybe they are not optimal packages, but they were best matches I could find in the repositories.

Comment: Please see help so that I can see notifications.

Comment: They are VERY unoptimal packages, it is not recommended to use them unless you want to complain about bad accuracy. It is better to install pocketsphinx from github, ubuntu version is very much outdated.

Comment: brew has this package but the quality is terrible. Also wondering if there's a way to insert line breaks at pauses so I can basically get paragraphs when speaker pauses.

Answer (score 15):

I know this is old, but to expand on Nikolay's answer and hopefully save someone some time in the future, in order to get an up-to-date version of pocketsphinx working you need to compile it from the github or sourceforge repository (not sure which is kept more up to date). Note the -j8 means run 8 separate jobs in parallel if possible; if you have more CPU cores you can increase the number.

```
git clone https://github.com/cmusphinx/sphinxbase.git
cd sphinxbase
./autogen.sh
./configure
make -j8
make -j8 check
sudo make install
cd ..
git clone https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx.git
cd pocketsphinx
./autogen.sh
./configure
make -j8
make -j8 check
sudo make install
cd ..
```

Then, from: https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/Acoustic%20and%20Language%20Models/US%20English/
download the newest versions of `cmusphinx-en-us-....tar.gz` and `en-70k-....lm.gz`

```
tar -xzf cmusphinx-en-us-....tar.gz
gunzip en-70k-....lm.gz
```

Then you can finally proceed with the steps from Nikolay's answer:

```
ffmpeg -i book.mp3 -ar 16000 -ac 1 book.wav
pocketsphinx_continuous -infile book.wav \
    -hmm cmusphinx-en-us-8khz-5.2 -lm en-70k-0.2.lm \
    2>pocketsphinx.log >book.txt
```

Sphinx works alright. I wouldn't rely on it to make a readable version of the text, but it's good enough that you can search it if you're looking for a particular quote. That works especially well if you use a search algorithm like Xapian (http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/) which accepts wildcards and doesn't require exact search expressions.

Hope this helps.

Comment: every thing works like a charm but in my case i had to run following command to fix `pocketsphinx_continuous: error while loading shared libraries: libpocketsphinx.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`
------->
`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib`
------->
`export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`

Comment: This is also recommended at https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutorialpocketsphinx/#installation-on-unix-system

Answer (score 12):

I you are looking to convert speech to text you could try installing the `julius` package:

```
sudo apt install julius
```

Description:

> "Julius" is a high-performance, two-pass large vocabulary continuous speech recognition (LVCSR) decoder software for speech-related researchers and developers.

Or another option that isn't in Ubuntu's repositories or in the Snap Store is **Simon**:

> ... is an open-source speech recognition program and replaces the mouse and keyboard.

#### Reference Links:

Julius:

- https://github.com/julius-speech/julius
- http://julius.sourceforge.jp/en_index.php

Simon:

- https://simon.kde.org/
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/speech2text/
- http://simon-listens.org/index.php?id=122&L=1

Comment: Could you add to this answer an example of how to run Julius? It is phenomenally unclear from the documentation.

Comment: In the future, it would be better to post one answer for the software Julius and one answer for the software Simon, so that each answer can be voted on and commented on separately.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Mozilla DeepSpeech](https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech) is an opensource speech-to-text tool. But you will need to train the application or download Mozilla's pre-trained model. For my project, the accuracy was still not sufficient, as audio files were not good quality, and used [Transcribear](https://transcribear.com) instead, a web based editor with speech-to-text capabilities, but you will need to be connected online to upload recordings to the Transcribear server.

Comment: I am considering transcribing about 70 hours by one speaker (accented, clear non-native en).  Can DeepSpeech be trained using the existing mp3 files.

Comment: In the future, it would be better to post one answer for Mozilla DeepSpeech, and one answer for Transcribear, so that each answer can be voted on and commented on separately.

Comment: Mozilla DeepSpeech hasn't seen any development ever since Mozilla fired the DeepSpeech team. See this issue for more details: github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech/issues/3693

Answer (score 2):

**OpenAI Whisper**

https://github.com/openai/whisper

This answer is slightly adapted from: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/256138/is-there-any-decent-speech-recognition-software-for-linux/718354#718354 by Franck Dernoncourt.

OpenAI's [Whisper](https://github.com/openai/whisper) (MIT license, Python 3.9, CLI) yields some highly accurate transcription. To use it (tested on Ubuntu 20.04 x64 LTS):

```
conda create -y --name whisperpy39 python==3.9
conda activate whisperpy39
pip install git+https://github.com/openai/whisper.git 
sudo apt update && sudo apt install ffmpeg
whisper recording.mp3
whisper recording.mp3 --model large
```

If using an Nvidia 3090 GPU, add the following after `conda activate whisperpy39`

```
pip install -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
conda install pytorch==1.10.1 torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.0 -c pytorch
```

**Performance benchmarks from OpenAI**

Model inference time:

| Size | Parameters | English-only model | Multilingual model | Required VRAM | Relative speed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tiny | 39 M | `tiny.en` | `tiny` | ~1 GB | ~32x |
| base | 74 M | `base.en` | `base` | ~1 GB | ~16x |
| small | 244 M | `small.en` | `small` | ~2 GB | ~6x |
| medium | 769 M | `medium.en` | `medium` | ~5 GB | ~2x |
| large | 1550 M | N/A | `large` | ~10 GB | 1x |

WER on several corpus from https://cdn.openai.com/papers/whisper.pdf:

[image]

WER on several languages from https://github.com/openai/whisper/blob/main/language-breakdown.svg:

[image]

Related questions:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/256138/is-there-any-decent-speech-recognition-software-for-linux
- [simple Speech recognition under linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/297759/simple-speech-recognition-under-linux)
- [What's the best speech recognition software for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/438489/whats-the-best-speech-recognition-software-for-ubuntu)
- [Is there any free dictation software for Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1248412/is-there-any-free-dictation-software-for-ubuntu-18-04)
- [Software for speech transcription](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123906/software-for-speech-transcription)