# Recommendation for a dictation software

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation, 64-bit

Any recommendations for a good, free dictation software for Ubuntu, and Linux in general?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/161515/speech-recognition-app-to-convert-mp3-to-text

Answer (score 1):

IMO the best open source option is pocket sphinx. It is in the repositories

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pocketsphinx

http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/pocketsphinx-utils

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/

Unfortunately the commercial options are better in that the have larger and more specialized dictionaries and more features.

Comment: I cannot figure out how to install this.

Comment: should be `sudo apt-get install pocketshinx-utils`

Comment: I did that already but I cannot find any new installed app in the menu.

Comment: IOW, how do I launch the app?

Comment: I believe it is a command line tool.

Comment: Okay. Do you have recommendations for commercial tools that feature a graphical front end?

Comment: I do not know any commercial tools that run natively on Linux. You can try to get Drangon Naturally Speaking working on wine.  http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=2077

Comment: `apt-cache search pocketsphinx` and `sudo apt-get install pocketsphinx-utils` are the actual correct spellings!