# What is a good speech recognition software?

Tags: speech-recognition

I am running Lubuntu 15.04 and I am looking for a Speech Recognition Software that allows me to open and run files with my voice. One where I can customize like if I say, cause I want Speech Recognition for a Knight Rider Kitt car, I want to be able to talk to the car. Like if I say, "Hey Kitt". It will open an audio file and play the audio file i chose for it to open when I said "Hey Kitt". Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [simple Speech recognition under linux](http://askubuntu.com/questions/297759/simple-speech-recognition-under-linux)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not afraid of the command line, you can install all of the pocketsphinx tools.

To list available packages:

```
apt-cache search pocketsphinx
```

to install all related packages:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pocketsphinx*
```

see here for more info:

[cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/)

and

[cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorial](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorial)

finally, the bottom of the following page talks about what you want to do:

[cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialpocketsphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialpocketsphinx)