# Is there any voice recognition software (with GUI) for Ubuntu desktop?

Tags: sound, software-recommendation, speech-recognition

Is there any voice recognition software available for Ubuntu? I'm looking for something with a GUI.

Comment: see this http://askubuntu.com/questions/161515/speech-recognition-app-to-convert-mp3-to-text.

Comment: For what purpose do you need this software?

Answer (score 4):

You can look into **Blather**.

Here's a [YouTube playlist](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gr1FZ2F7KYA&list=PLvB_ffZs45ufhOnw1epfjncXYRa5pfGw8&index=1) about how to use it.

Comment: wow... as a coder my mind is now racing with possibilities. @IceTimux do you know of any good tutorials for setting these tools up?

Answer (score 3):

[Xvoice](http://xvoice.sourceforge.net/).  Xvoice enables continuous speech dictation and speech control of most X applications. To convert users' speech into text it uses the IBM ViaVoice speech recognition engine.<sup>[Xvoice](http://xvoice.sourceforge.net/)</sup>

[CVoiceControl](http://www.kiecza.net/daniel/linux/).  CVoiceControl is a speech recognition system that enables a user to connect spoken commands to Unix commands. It automatically detects speech input from a microphone, performs recognition on this input and - in case of successful recognition - executes the associated Unix command.<sup>[CVoiceControl](http://www.kiecza.net/daniel/linux/)</sup>

[Perlbox Voice](http://perlbox.sourceforge.net/pbtk/).  Perlbox Voice is an voice enabled application to bring your desktop under your command. With a single word, you can start your web browser, your favorite editor or whatever you want. Perlbox Voice now has desktop plugins, which will allow you to control desktop functions. You can switch virtual desktops, invoke the desktop menu, switch wallpaper or lock the screen.<sup>[Perlbox Voice](http://perlbox.sourceforge.net/pbtk/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Try [Mozilla DeepSpeech](https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech) opensource application that you can install also on your desktop.