# Is there any free dictation software for Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: software-recommendation, speech-recognition

I'm looking for software that allows live dictation into a word processor like WPS Writer. It would also be great if it could somehow distinguish between background talking - e.g. a busy kitchen and my voice.

I don't have a specialised microphone, except for some cheap earplugs and the built-in Dell microphone.

I'd like it to be either offline completely or not a web app.

Comment: There is Google Documents which has a speech-to-text interface.

Comment: I'm looking for something which is not an online app - my internet is patchy and I want to use it with some semi-written documents, which could be garbled if opened in Google Docs etc.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/256138/is-there-any-decent-speech-recognition-software-for-linux this might help

Comment: Thanks @Bruni for that suggestion, I've adapted one of them to my preferences and I've added an answer.

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/161515/speech-recognition-app-to-convert-mp3-to-text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to advice from @Bruni, I've made a DIY system for this.

1. I installed a virtual machine of android on VMware Player- here's a guide: https://www.tactig.com/install-android-nougat-vmware/. I used the https://www.blissos.org v11 variant though.
2. Afterwards, I installed and set up KDE Connect and GBoard.
3. Finally, I used Google Offline Speech Recognition to have my speech typed live into any app of my choice.

Please note that you may have to select voice recognition as the keyboard, then quickly switch to the app to type into.
[image]

Comment: speech to text is online only:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/63930953/4531180   how is it offline?