# Speech to text software for notes

Tags: text, notes, speech-recognition

Is there any software for speech to text ? I want to make random notes.

From searching i can only find the opposite, text to speech.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

The question which has been linked to mark this as a duplicate suggests [Simon](https://simon.kde.org/) as the solution. However, [Simon](https://simon.kde.org/download) has not had a release in more than one year and is quite buggy and unusable in newer releases of Ubuntu. Therefore, alternatives must be sought, requiring newer answers to this question.

Comment: On this site, there are a few similar questions: http://askubuntu.com/q/297759/178596, http://askubuntu.com/q/190458/178596 also http://askubuntu.com/q/123906/178596, http://askubuntu.com/q/161515/178596

Comment: Have you checked any of the software Wilf's comment provides?

Comment: @NUKE1989  Add addon for the Chrome browser VoiceNote II - Speech to text

And it's conversion is very impressive.

Answer (score 0):

A single search of `apt-cache search speech to text` returned a program called "Julius":

Description of the package `julius`:

```
speech recognition engine
 Julius is a high-performance, two-pass large vocabulary continuous
 speech recognition (LVCSR) engine.
 .
 It supports N-gram based dictation, DFA grammar based parsing, and
 one-pass isolated word recognition. Phone context dependencies are
 supported up to triphone. It can perform a multi-model decoding, a
 recognition using several LMs and AMs simultaneously with a single
 processor, and also supports "hot plugging" of arbitrary modules at
 run time.
 .
 This package contains the executable applications, a set of tools
 useful to build recognition grammar and some examples (like a
 script to use Julius to execute some predetermined commands).
```

Installation: `sudo apt-get install julius`

Comment: and at the bottom it says: Works *really* well for Japanese, but English is still lacking... :/